# Oracle out parameter cast - c#

Tags: c#, oracle, casting, odp.net

Having an issue with an older application I am supporting. The data access is CSLA .Net and there is a line that updates a newly created entity id with the value from an out parameter. This is defined in the database as NUMERIC(10,0). The code looks like this:

```
OracleParameter opID = new OracleParameter("P_ID", OracleDbType.Int64);
//... do some stuff and save the new entity to the db
_id = (long)opID.Value;
```

This used to be fine on windows XP with version 9.x of ODP .Net. On a Windows 7 box with the latest version the cast fails and the return data type of the parameter is Decimal despite being explicitly declared as Int64. This looks to me like a bug/weird behavior in the new version of ODP .Net. Is there a workaround or something I can do to fix the issue, preferably without changing my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `Convert.ToInt64` instead, this will handle both cases: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c5w856c.aspx

Comment: I will probably end up using that, thanks! I am trying to avoid modifying that code because it looks like it was generated by a tool. Altough at this point it looks like nobody has ownership of this project so I might as well just take it over and clean things up a bit.

Comment: Convert.ToInt64 fails with an invalid cast exception unfortunatley.

Unable to cast object of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

I'm at a loss why a parameter that is declared as Int64 returns a Decimal value from the database. I can see the parameter type as Int64 yet the value returned is Decimal.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is further detailed on the Oracle forums here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=406872;

There seems to have been a slight change that affects how Oracle data types are being hadled. The quick fix was to do a double cast (long)((OracleDecimal)opId.Value).